# How to toggle a url parameter's value in the href attribute of an a tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery toggle the value of the last parameter in an href attribute in an A tag.

To toggle between:

```
target.php?id=123&search=selected&format=html&pricing=false
```

and:

```
target.php?id=123&search=selected&format=html&pricing=true
```

I got a pretty good start:

```
$('#option-include-prices').on('click', function(){

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('download-button');

    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        var button = buttons[i];

        var href = $(button).attr('href');

        var bool = (href.indexOf('false') > 0) ? 'true' : 'false';

        $(button).attr('href', href.replace('false', bool)); // obviously a problem

    }

});
```

So I can find if the value is true or false & set a variable accordingly - but the replace() method obviously won't work if the value has been set to true already (i.e. can't toggle it back to false)

what method should be used to toggle that variable?

Comment: your last line is only toggling it if the href contains 'false', not the other way around.  One way is to wrap the last line in a conditional based on the value of bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function called `updateParam` so you can, optimally, use this for more than just toggling a boolean off and on in a link.  I also wrote a wrapper for the function so you can see how to use it.

```js
function updateParam (url, param, value) {
  return url.replace(/(.*?\?|)(.*?)=(.*?)(&|$)/g, function (ignore,starter,key,v,ending) {
    if (key === param) {
      v = value;
    }
    return starter + key + "=" + v + ending;
  });
}

$liveUpdate = $("#liveUpdate");

$("#boolTest").on("click", function () {
  var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
  $liveUpdate.attr("href",
    updateParam($liveUpdate.attr("href"),"pricing",isChecked)
  );
  
  console.log($liveUpdate.attr("href"));
}).trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Toggle off and on this checkbox to test the code: <input type="checkbox" id="boolTest" />
<hr />
<a id="liveUpdate" href="target.php?id=123&search=selected&format=html&pricing=false">testing link</a>
```